# Bootstrap 3 columns not displaying horizontally on desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm familiar with bootstrap and it's responsive stacking but in this case, I seem to be getting the stacking at any screen size. Other two column rows on the page are not doing this so I wonder if anyoune could take a look and see what my tired eyes are missing.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kylebellamy/2oyt71gL/)

My HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="col-md-6 pull-left" style="margin-bottom:40px;">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1100x1591" style="max-width:400px;" alt=""/>
      </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right" style="font-weight:bold; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:40px;">
            <div style="height: 2px; background-color: #9e1e22;">
  <span style="background-color: white; position: relative; top: -0.5em; color:#9e1e22; font-size:18px;">
    Cybersecurity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  </span>
</div>
<div>
While information security and privacy are different, they are interdependent. For that reason, Navigate teams with select partner firms that specialize in cybersecurity to provide services such as highly technical security assessments, penetration testing, or application evaluations. These partnerships enable us to provide one integrated team for all your information protection, privacy and cybersecurity assessment needs.</div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set a `margin-line` at your `div` so the element becomes bigger than 50% and stack.
You can solve using

```
  <div class="col-md-6 pull-right" style="font-weight: bold; padding-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
```

You can see the fiddle.

I have also add a `div class="row"` and `img-responsive` at your `image`, but are not necessary.

https://jsfiddle.net/2oyt71gL/3/

Comment: Ah, got it! I appreciate being able to keep the even numbered columns so this works out perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your code and I was able to fix it by changing your second div class="col-md-6" to col-md-5 and it no longer stacks until you start resizing the screen.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 pull-left" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1100x1591" style="max-width: 400px;" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 pull-right" style="font-weight: bold; margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
            <div style="height: 2px; background-color: #9e1e22;">
                <span style="background-color: white; position: relative; top: -0.5em; color: #9e1e22; font-size: 18px;">
                    Cybersecurity&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                While information security and privacy are different, they are interdependent. For that reason, Navigate teams with select partner firms that specialize in cybersecurity to provide services such as highly technical security assessments, penetration testing, or application evaluations. These partnerships enable us to provide one integrated team for all your information protection, privacy and cybersecurity assessment needs.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked as well but lost the even column numbers.